# how to improve preg_match_all output structure?

Tags: php, preg-match

look at this piece of code:

```
preg_match_all('/\[user\](.*?)\[\/user\]/' , $_POST['reply'] , $match);
```

$_POST['reply'] value is "Hello [user]pooya[/user] and [user]zahra[/user]" but the structure of $match is arrays in arrays ! something like:

```
 Array
(


    => Array


        (


    => pooya
                [1] => zahra
            )

        [1] => Array
            (

    => pooya
    [1] => zahra
            )

    )
```

is there any trick to organize the output of preg_match_all? for example a simple array with the tag values as the elements of the array?

Comment: You can improve it significantly by consistently indenting the output (does your code look like that =) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the result is a multi dimensional array, you could just pull the values from this array multi dimensional as is.
Try something like :

```
  echo $yourVariable[2] ['pooya'];
```

Although your array doesn't seem to be structured quiet correctly.

You might want to structure it like this:

```
$pooya = array (

 array(

 "group"=>"pooya",
 "name"=>"zarah"),

 array(
 "group"=>"Pooya",
 "name"=>"Zarah"
 )

 );

 echo $pooya[0] ['group'];

 echo $pooya[1] ['name'];
```

---

OK have you read this on:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

```
preg_match_all ( string $pattern , string $subject [, array &$matches [, int $flags =        PREG_PATTERN_ORDER [, int $offset = 0 ]]] )
```

PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern matches, $matches[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) is an array of strings matched by the first parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

```
 <?php
 preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|U",
     "<b>example: </b><div align=left>this is a test</div>",
     $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
  echo $out[0][0] . ", " . $out[0][1] . "\n";
  echo $out[1][0] . ", " . $out[1][1] . "\n";
  ?>
```

Comment: I just want to extract the names trapped in user tag and iterate through them and so I used preg_match_all but the result is totally unstructured.

Comment: ok I supplied a link above maybe that will help you to understand the use of the preg_match_all() function.

Comment: where is the user tag coming from ?